# Каким образом мы получаем переменную вне функции?

Tags: javascript, ajax

В данном коде, по клику на кнопку мы вытягиваем массив объектов из сервера. Затем добавляем эти объекты в разметку.

Вопрос: каким образом мы получаем значение переменной **response** вне функции **getPosts**, что является её аргументом **(cb)** и что вызывает **cb(response)**?

```js
const btn = document.getElementById("get-posts");
const container = document.getElementById("container");

function getPosts(cb) {
  let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("GET", "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts");
  xhr.send();
  xhr.addEventListener("load", () => {
    const response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
    cb(response);
  });
}

function renderPosts(response) {
  const fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
  response.forEach(post => {
    const card = document.createElement("div");
    card.classList.add("card");

    const title = document.createElement("h5");
    title.classList.add("card-title");
    title.textContent = post.title;

    const article = document.createElement("p");
    article.classList.add("card-text");
    article.textContent = post.body;

    card.appendChild(title);
    card.appendChild(article);
    fragment.appendChild(card);
  });
  container.appendChild(fragment);
}

btn.addEventListener("click", e => {
  getPosts(renderPosts);
});
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как вернуть значение из события или из функции обратного вызова? Или хотя бы дождаться их окончания](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554290/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%98%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%85%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8f-%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b6)

Comment: Человек попросил объяснить как это работает, а ему сразу минуса и тревоги. Ну хз...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас есть функция `renderPosts(response)` response - её аргумент, и есть функция `getPosts(cb)` cb - её аргумент.

Смотрим по коду:

```
btn.addEventListener("click", e => {
    getPosts(renderPosts);
});
```

Добавляется ивент клика на кнопку, который вызывает функцию getPosts и ей уже в качестве аргумента передаётся функция renderPosts (только название функции без скобок это "передача" функции, со скобками, аля renderPosts() это уже вызов функции).

То есть, вот этот код: `cb(response);` аналогичен вот этому: `renderPosts(response)`.

В итоге, мы можем по-другому показать наш код так:

```js
const btn = document.getElementById("get-posts");
    const container = document.getElementById("container");

     function getPosts() {
      let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open("GET", "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts");
      xhr.send();
      xhr.addEventListener("load", () => {
        const response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        renderPosts(response);
      });
    }

    function renderPosts(response) {
      const fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
      response.forEach(post => {
        const card = document.createElement("div");
        card.classList.add("card");

        const title = document.createElement("h5");
        title.classList.add("card-title");
        title.textContent = post.title;

        const article = document.createElement("p");
        article.classList.add("card-text");
        article.textContent = post.body;

        card.appendChild(title);
        card.appendChild(article);
        fragment.appendChild(card);
      });
      container.appendChild(fragment);
    }

    btn.addEventListener("click", e => {
      getPosts();
    });
```

Или даже так:

```js
        const btn = document.getElementById("get-posts");
        const container = document.getElementById("container");

         function getPosts() {
          let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
          xhr.open("GET", "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts");
          xhr.send();
          xhr.addEventListener("load", () => {
            const response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            const fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
          response.forEach(post => {
            const card = document.createElement("div");
            card.classList.add("card");

            const title = document.createElement("h5");
            title.classList.add("card-title");
            title.textContent = post.title;

            const article = document.createElement("p");
            article.classList.add("card-text");
            article.textContent = post.body;

            card.appendChild(title);
            card.appendChild(article);
            fragment.appendChild(card);
          });
          container.appendChild(fragment);
          });
        }

        btn.addEventListener("click", e => {
          getPosts();
        });
```

То есть, выходит что мы не получаем значение переменной response вне функции getPosts. Потому что всё структурировано - создаётся видимость того что данные используются вне функции, но по сути всё происходит внутри getPosts.

Answer (score -1):

```html
var param; 

function renderPosts(response) {
    param = respons;
}
```

если я вас правильно понял